# Variable scoping in KDB

Tags: kdb

```
getQuotes: {[sym;start;end]
  url: f[sym;start;end]
  {some_test} {request.quotes[url;x`next_page_token]} \ request.quotes[url;0b] 
  }
```

I have a `while` loop. The issue I'm having is that `url` is out of scope for the while lambda:

```
'url
  [2]  alpaca.q:47: .alpaca.getQuotes@:{request.quotes[url;x`next_page_token]}
                                                                             
                                                       ^
```

I have read on this post that this is by design:
[Variable scope propagation in k](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60448063/variable-scope-propagation-in-k), but it doesn't really give me a solution.

I've tried to wrap it in a unary, which didn't work.

I made `url` global with `url::`, this **did work**, but it's not very clean.

Is there a preferred pattern for passing `url` into the lambda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass variables into the inner lambdas as parameters:

```
getQuotes: {[sym;start;end]
  url: f[sym;start;end]
  {some_test} {[x;url]request.quotes[url;x`next_page_token]}[;url] \ request.quotes[url;0b] 
  }
```

Comment: The `x` is the response from the first iteration; the result gets fed back into the loop until some_test = 0. I actually didn't this would work, but I'll give it a shot now.

Comment: Yep, as predicted, x is now out of scope. I tried variants of this (passing `x` through), but no luck. I'm not sure this is possible without a global.

Comment: Oh I see now, I think you want a projection for the scan to work. I've edited my answer above for clarity. ```{some_test} {[x;url]request.quotes[url;x`next_page_token]}[;url] \ request.quotes[url;0b]```

Comment: That's the one! Thank you! :)